# Update mouse position on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I came across this website's [work page](https://goodpatch.com/work) and would like to recreate the xray effect of each of the card element.

Here's my code for the xray effect: https://codepen.io/carljustineoyales/pen/yLMEVYd

HTML

```
  <section class="banner">
    <h1>this is a banner page</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="projects" id="projects">
 <div class="cardlist" >
    <div class="cardlist__grid" >
      <div class="card" id="card" onmouseover="setSize()" onmouseout="resetSize()">
        <div class="card__category">
          category
        </div>
        <div class="card__thumbnail">
          
        </div>
        <div class="card__info">
          <div class="card__title">title</div>
          <div class="card__date">date</div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div class="card" id="card">
        <div class="card__category">
          category
        </div>
        <div class="card__thumbnail">
          
        </div>
        <div class="card__info">
          <div class="card__title">title</div>
          <div class="card__date">date</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cardlist--skeleton" id="skeleton">
    <div class="cardlist--skeleton--bg"></div>
    <div class="cardlist__grid">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__category">
          category
        </div>
        <div class="card__thumbnail card__thumbnail--black">
          
        </div>
        <div class="card__info">
          <div class="card__title">title</div>
          <div class="card__date">date</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card__category">
          category
        </div>
        <div class="card__thumbnail card__thumbnail--black">
          
        </div>
        <div class="card__info">
          <div class="card__title">title</div>
          <div class="card__date">date</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

SCSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.banner {
  height: 100vh;
}

.projects {
  max-width: 1440px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 100px auto;
  // padding: 100px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.cardlist {
  width: 100%;


  color: #000;

  &__grid {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;

  }

  &--skeleton {
    --x: 0;
    --y: 0;
    --size: 0px;
    clip-path: circle(var(--size) at var(--x) var(--y));
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    // clip-path: circle(100px at 0 0);
    // clip-path: circle(300px at 0% 0%);
    transition: clip-path 0.1s ease;

    &--bg {

      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #838383;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #838383;

  }
}

.card {
  padding: 50px;

  &__thumbnail {
    width: 500px;
    height: 644px;
    background-color: #838383;

    &--black {
      background-color: #000;
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
 let mouseX=0
    let mouseY=0
    let size = 0;
    
    const projects = document.querySelector('#projects');

    function setSize() {
      size = 200
      skeleton.style.setProperty('--size', size + "px");
    }

    function resetSize() {
      size = 0
      skeleton.style.setProperty('--size', size + "px");
      
    }

    function updateCoordinates(event) {

      
      mouseX = event.pageX - projects.offsetLeft ;
      mouseY = event.pageY - projects.offsetTop ;


      skeleton.style.setProperty('--x', mouseX + "px");
      skeleton.style.setProperty('--y', mouseY+ "px");
    
    }
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find a solution for the updating cursor position while scrolling, also the hover animation became laggy when you open the console. Is there a way to update the cursor position on scroll and why the animation became laggy when the console is open.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski cursor position update on scroll

Comment: Did you try window.onscroll ?
This site should help you https://riptutorial.com/html5-canvas/example/19534/mouse-coordinates-after-resizing--or-scrolling-

Comment: @Shahabaz .. will try to implement that in my code, hope it works.